# How do I manually add a dependency to Gradle's cache via command line?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

There is an issue with the repository we use on a vpn when downloading with large libraries, the workaround solution for this on maven was to download the library manually and add it to local repo via command line.

Now I am working in a gradle project that uses the same repository in the backend, with the same problem but I have no idea how to do the same actions with Gradle.

Comment: if there are no other local build clashes .... just point to the local maven repo if jars are already in it ... `mavenlocal()`